# Scoring rules (log-loss vs. F1-weighted) and RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, scoring-rules

I read multiple posts about scoring rules during cross-validation and the fact that the log-loss score is a proper scoring rule and, correct me if I am wrong, any threshold based approach is a improper scoring rule for model optimisation.

However, when I perform a hyperparameter optimisation `RandomizedSearchCV` and set scoring to `"f1_weighted"` the performance metrics on the hold-out test set is better than the with the scoring set to `'neg_log_loss'`. **However, I am not sure whether it is justified to use `f1_weighted` in this case?**

Furthermore, when I plot the f1_weighted during training, it is very much underfitting (train = 0.64 and test is 0.75) when compared to the hold-out test performance, while this is not the case for the log-loss score (train = 0.6 and test = 0.58). Does this indicate that the log loss approach is the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log-loss and F1 scores really can't be compared. The log loss evaluates the full probability model. The F1 score suffers from (1) being based on an assumption of a probability cutoff (often a hidden assumption of p = 0.5) and (2) [ignoring true negatives](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/192765/28500).

"The way to go," as you will read on many threads on this site, is to (1) develop a well-calibrated probability model with a strictly proper scoring rule, for example log loss, and then (2) choose a probability cutoff (if needed) that represents your tradeoff between costs of false-negative and false-positive assignments. With a well calibrated model and costs scaled so that `c` is the cost of a false positive and `1-c` the cost of a false negative, you minimize your cost by choosing a probability cutoff of `c`. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/441734/28500) for details and links to further reading. If you think in terms of relative costs, things like F1 score will take care of themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was not trying to compare log-loss and F1 directly. What I wanted to emphasise was that when I optimise my hyperparameters during cross-validation and use log-loss as scoring argument then I obtain a poorer performing model (when looking at the confusion matrix) when compared to using the F1 as scoring argument. So, let me rephrase just to see if I understand: 1. perform hyperparameter optimisation with log-loss. 2. Set a threshold c that will be used to then classify the data (let's say threshold of 0.6) to obtain the optimal balance between TP/TN and FN/FP

Comment: @Oorschelp you understand correctly. My main point is that using F1 as a training criterion can be unreliable. Log-loss, however, is only one of many potential [proper scoring rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) for training. See links from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/441734/28500) for other possibilities if you have particular relative costs in mind to start. With a well-calibrated model then set your threshold to represent relative costs. You might need to play around some if the model isn't well calibrated; see the answer I linked above in this comment.

Comment: One last question: Are you by any chance familiar with SciKit learn in python? Because I don't think I can include the threshold in the RandomizedSearchCV from Python during training. Or would it be that 1. hyperparameter optimisation with log-loss 2. fit the trained optimised model 3. obtain the predict_proba for hold-out test set and then set a threshold? This seems to me that it would be prone to overfit?

Comment: @Oorschelp sorry, don't use SciKit Learn. Your outline is OK. To evaluate overfitting, repeat the _entire modeling process_ (all 3 outlined steps) on multiple bootstrapped samples of your data and evaluate performance on the full original data sample. That's the standard "optimism bootstrap," providing information on bias, overfitting, and non-parametric estimates of coefficient errors. See for example [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64803/28500), [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59126/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/373431/28500).